# C++ fast equality function

Tags: c++, templates, macros, equality

I want to use equality function instead operator "==" to prevent accidental assignment. I can use macro:

```
#define is_equal_macro(X,Y) X == Y

// somewhere in code: 
if (is_equal_macro(a,b)) {...}
```

but many sources call to avoid macro by using inline and template functions. So I wrote the following function:

```
template<class T1, class T2> inline bool
    is_equal_template(T1 const & a, T2 const & b) {
        return a == b;
}

// somewhere in code: 
if (if_equal_template(a,b)) {...}
```

but it is slower than macro in 1.6 times.
How can I write equality function in template style without time losses?

UPD: the full code version

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

#define is_equal_macro(X,Y) X == Y

template<class T1, class T2> inline bool
    is_equal_template(T1 const & a, T2 const & b) {
        return a == b;
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    size_t iter_num = 1e9;
    int a = 3;
    double b = 2.0;
    std::clock_t start;
    double duration;

    start = std::clock();

    for(size_t i = 0; i <= iter_num; ++i) {
        if (is_equal_macro(a, b)) {

        }
    }

    duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << duration << std::endl;

    start = std::clock();

    for(size_t i = 0; i <= iter_num; ++i) {
        if (is_equal_template(a, b)) {

        }
    }

    duration = ( std::clock() - start ) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    std::cout << duration << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turn on optimizations.

Comment: The code you present is clearly not the code you're using. Since the function name varies. It is a good idea to copy and paste real code.

Comment: What's the actual need for such macro or template? Explain your use case please!

Comment: It rarely matters if debug is 1.6x slower on a trivial and rare operation.  Provide compiler flags and settings when talking about profiling; you are probaly profiling a debug build.

Comment: A decent (and properly set up) compiler should warn you about accidental assignment in if-clauses, e.g. `if(a = b)` [clang++](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/TH8tcdVX4hL1odbb) [g++](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/SV52xqPXMO6Fce48)

Comment: If you really want to just not use `==`, you can also just `#define EQ ==`. I wouldn't recommend it, but that would at least solve your worries with minimal extra work to do, and it doesn't fall too far towards the evil side on the macro sane/evil scale.

Comment: *"I want to use equality function to prevent accidental assignment."*  Your compiler already has that feature built-in.  Just turn on compiler warnings.

Comment: If you're compiling with optimizations, your assembly will probably look like this: `callq clock; movq %rax, %rbx; callq clock` That is, the loops are entirely dropped, and you're measuring essentially the time of a `clock()` call. If you're not compiling with optimizations, I'd appreciate to know why.

Comment: Code review? Unit testing? This should catch these problems

Answer (score 1):

Using `==` really shouldn't be an issue. Usually people overload operators so that they can use `==` on their objects, not the other way around. Also like people suggested turn on compiler optimization.

Answer (score 0):

Some coding conventions (for old compilers that does not warn about assignment in IF-s)
suggest to place the constant before the var...
**E.g:**

```
int rc = DoSmthWithReturnErrorCode();
if(0 == rc) { puts('success'); }
```

this way, if you happen to miss the second `=` you get compilation error.

but, again as stated, you shouldn't worry about `==`,
only look at the compilation warnings.

Comment: This won't have any advantage if both sides are variables.

Comment: @Thomas Matthews correct, but will still work for 90%+ of the cases.